# Limit on a size of request for online predictions on Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am trying to send a request to Cloud ML Engine and the feature vector is composed of 150,000 float values. With `float16` precision and serialized as `base64` this gets me to around 1.8 MB, and the limit for ML Engine requests is 1.57 MB (1572864 bytes).

Is this a hard limit of the API? Is there a way to still perform online requests or is the feature vector just too large for the service?

Comment: Are these images are arbirary feature vectors?

Comment: Arbitrary feature vectors. Actually 500 words embedded with word2vec, which turns each word into 300 floats. Having the pretrained embeddings in the model was the first option, but that hits the 250 MB model limit. Taking only a subset of the embedding vocab (appearing in training set) is another option I see (but don't like), or trimming the documents at 300 words, which makes the feature vector 90k long, which fits. But I see those a bit as workarounds...

Comment: The 1.5 Mb limit is a hard limit for now. The 250 Mb can be updated per project, but with caveats (much more likely to OOM, autoscaling takes longer, etc.)

Comment: @rhaertel80 Are there any updates to these limits? I want to test Google Cloud ML engine, but cant't find anywhere in the documentation the possibility of changing model size and request size.

Comment: We can easily update your model size limit if you send a request to cloudml-feedback@google.com. Please mention the request size in the thread and we'll see what can be done.